# Delete a TextEdit document in iCloud

Tags: icloud, macos, textedit

I would like to delete a TextEdit document stored in iCould.

The only solution I found was to

- open the document
- move the document to the hard disk "File → Move To ..."
- delete it locally

Any better solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems quite counter-intuitive, but...

1. In TextEdit, select **File > Open…**
2. Press the iCloud button at top left.

Then:

- drag the icon you want to delete to the Trash in the Dock
- or control/right click the file icon you want to delete and choose the Move to Trash option (pictured below)
- or press <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>backspace</kbd> (the backspace key is labelled with a left-facing arrow)

[image: Move to Trash option in TextEdit Open dialog]

Answer (score 4):

- Mac OS X Lion and Mountain Lion
- From the Apple () menu, choose System Preferences.
- Click iCloud, and verify that you are signed in.
- Click the Manage button to view the data you have stored in iCloud.
- Select any of the apps below Manage Storage, select the document or data you wish to   delete from that app, and click the Delete button to remove the item. The data will be removed from your storage allocation and from all of your devices.

via - http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4847

Comment: Thanks I was hoping for a quicker solution but it's already better then the "move to" solution: the overview with the file sizes is surely a nice addition.

Answer (score 3):

From TextEdit's Open dialogue (File > Open...), you can select the file(s) you wish to delete and press CMD-DELETE (⌘⌫). This will also work with any other app supporting iCloud.

Comment: Where exactly do you select files currently stored in iCloud?

Comment: @patrix I suspect is suggesting using this keyboard shortcut within the File > Open dialogue... I've upvoted this answer and I'll edit this suggestion into mine (where I do explain the File > Open dialogue). vrtcl1dvoshun: perhaps you could edit your answer to include this detail, too.

Answer (score 1):

first click tin the top corner to open spotlight, you will find this right beside the notification centre (if you are running mountain lion) then type the file name and click show in finder, after this on the bottom of finder it will show you where is is stored. this should say iCloud.